# vimrc: imap Alt + an accented character

Tags: vim

I have a few keystrokes (like `<M-[>`) `imap`'d to executing some actions in my `.vimrc`, e.g.

```
imap <M-[> <C-o>:silent !audtool --playback-seek-relative -3<CR>
```

for seeking in audacious while typing (for transcripting recorded speech). I wanted to do the same for Czech keyboard layout, which happens to have `ú` (u-acute) in that position. So I tried the obvious

```
imap <M-ú> <C-o>:silent !audtool --playback-seek-relative -3<CR>
```

which does not work. What is the solution here? Tried `:help key-notation` and google without success. A solution only working in gvim (and not in terminal) is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Vim has an ancient method to handle input – it is represented as a byte (character) queue, not as a keystroke sequence queue. I guess, the character `<M-ú>` (yes, it should be a char) just does not exist, like as `<C-1>` doesn’t. You can make sure of it by pressing `<C-v><M-ú>` in input mode – a plain `ú` or nothing would be typed. So there is no way to map `<M-ú>` to something either.

But! Hence Vim is not well to handle different external layouts than basic QWERTY by design, it provide an his own (internal) mechanism for supporting second layout.

If you do `:set keymap=czech`, you would be able to switch input language inside Vim by `<C-6>`, and forget about mapping mess – in mappings `<M-[>` (as well as `z`, `2`, etc) would mean one key chord in both layouts.

BTW, this is actually an only way to adequately use Vim for a language which has a layout that is completely different than QWERTY (e. g. Cyrillic).

Comment: Well, since I am running in gvim and the keyboard layout is handled by X11, does that mean that I will replace that with a gvim-only keymap, and switch between those with different keys than usually? That sounds quite awkward.

Comment: @eudoxos Yes, that is quite awkward, but true. As one who do that (as well as many Russian Vim-users do, I believe), I can assure you, that it is much less uneasy than it seems at first sight – Vim already has quite a lot ‘awkward’ shortcuts :-) You can remap `<C-6>` to whatever you want, of course.

Comment: @eudoxos Also, I think, it’s worth to be mentioned explicitly that `langmap` won’t help in this case – with Meta. (Although it may be useful for you if you are not using it yet.)